# JavaScript - Exporting a harcoded array vs creating one

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have a file `data.js`, which contains an array of some data that will be imported somewhere (*eg. a React component*).

**EXAMPLE A:**

```js
const DATA = [
  {
    firstName: 'jim',
    lastName: 'beam',
    fullName: 'jim beam'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'jack',
    lastName: 'daniels',
    fullName: 'jack daniels'
  }
];

export default DATA;
```

Ok, cool. Thing is, we're writing out the `fullName` property, which could be gathered by combining `firstName` and `lastName`. This is a very trivial example for clarity, so bear with me. We could also do something like this:

**EXAMPLE B:**

```js
const DATA = [
  { firstName: 'jim', lastName: 'beam' },
  { firstName: 'jack', lastName: 'daniels' }
];

export default DATA.map(person => ({
   ...person,
   fullName: `${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}`
});
```

Heck, we could even do this!

**EXAMPLE C:**

```js
const DATA = ['jim beam', 'jack daniels'];

export default DATA.map(person => {
  const [firstName, lastName] = person.split(' ');
  return {
    firstName,
    lastName,
    fullName: person
  };
};
```

So, imagine you have a huuge list of data, where multiple values could be derived from one initial value. My question is how would examples **B** and **C** differ from just hardcoding everything right off the bat like example **A**?

If you had hundreds of items, examples **B** and **C** could have much less overhead, a smaller file size, and can reduce potential typos... But, we're declaring an array and then exporting a different one, which I assume could have a performance dip? Thoughts?

Comment: "hundreds of items" is not going to be a concern. "millions of items", maybe. Do whatever looks better to you.

Comment: I don't know about performance but I suspect the hit would be mild. Personally, I don't like `C` because if one of the strings is formatted wrong, stuff can break -- but if you can guarantee the correct format before exporting, then my concern is moot.

Comment: "*can reduce potential typos*" - you could still misspell the names. But the main problem of your initial snippet is that it could contain **inconsistent** data, which could be a source of bugs/problems. So for integrity alone, go for canonical single-source data!

Comment: Usually you have a tradeoff between speed and memory usage. You should optimize whichever of these is causing a bottleneck in your situation. Most of the time you want to optimize the developer time spent on building and maintaining the code.

Answer (score 1):

How about a class with a getter that evaluates `fullName` on access?
It offers smaller in-memory size, and doesn't have a performance issue because `fullName` property of each datum is not computed until they are imported, and accessed.

```js
class Person {
    constructor(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    get fullName() {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`
    }
}

let a = new Person('Charles', 'Martel');
console.log(a.fullName)

// expected result: "Charles Martel"
```

Your data can then be declared as the following.

```js
const DATA = [
  new Person('jim', 'beam'),
  new Person('jack','daniels')
];
```

Comment: That was a poor wording on my part. I edited the answer to clarify. Thx.